# How to add a DateTimepicker when you edit a cell of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-4.0

I've created 4 Data GridView Dynamically. The Data Source of each of the gridviews is a DataTable. It has 3 columns, first column type being string, second and third column being DateTime. The First Column has static data. On clicking the second and third column cells, I want a DateTimePicker to come allowing user to select DateTime Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be possible to do changes doing DataBindings, but I choose not to look into it.
Instead of attaching DataTable as DataSource, I took e.g mentioned here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) customised it as per my needs and then created DataGridViewColumns and iterated over Rows of DataTable to fill up content. I did write any template code.

Answer (score 1):

You may need a template Row, see details here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/netfxbcl/thread/2677158c-76a3-4e65-8ae4-18373a80516e

Comment: The problem is how to handle columns with DataTable as datasource, I'm not able to think about how to do that.

Comment: you need to handle the row data bound even of the grid, there you can arrange assigning appropriate values to each DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - Make a new DataTable (that has the schema you need). Then add 2 or 3 controls (one for string input, and either CheckBox or 2 radioButtons that will determine which DateTime column will be filled). When user clicks on DateTimePicker, it will fill one column, then he can selects/deselects the CheckBox, and select the second date. When all values are properly set, user can click the Submit button that:
- Fills the DataTable with proper data.
- Changes the DataGridView's DataSource

This is just my idea on how you can solve this, there may be another way.